# android bufferedwriter - can't find the text file

Tags: android, bufferedwriter

I'm new to programming (just learned Java several months ago) and usually found a lot of help online by searching through here, but this time I'm pretty stumped.

I'm attempting to save sensor data on my Android phone to a text file in the storage, and pulling the text file out later using the usb cord. However, after I run the app on the phone, I can't seem to find it in the folders in Internal Storage.

I did include this line in my manifest to rule out the issue of permissions.

```
    <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The boolean save_data is triggered when I press a button on the screen and I verified that the button is working by displaying on/off on my screen when the button is pressed.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
synchronized (this) {
    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER: 
        A_x_value.setText(Float.toString(event.values[0]));
        A_y_value.setText(Float.toString(event.values[1]));
        A_z_value.setText(Float.toString(event.values[2]));

        if (save_data == true) {
            SaveButton_Label.setText("On");

            String datastring = "A: " + Float.toString(event.values[0]) + " " + Float.toString(event.values[1]) + " " + Float.toString(event.values[2]);
            try
            {
                File f = new File("sensordata.txt");
                FileWriter fr = new FileWriter(f);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fr);
                out.write(datastring);
                out.close();
            }

            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception");
            }

        } else {
            SaveButton_Label.setText("Off");
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

}

I appreciate any help you guys can provide. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new File instance, you have to define whole path including the external storage path.

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "sensordata.txt");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, but I still can't seem to find the text file. I also couldn't find the application folder in the internal storage when I could plainly see the applications folders for the other apps on my phone... so could it be a problem larger than just the code? I've been playing around inside the "myfirstapp" package from the android website (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) and running it on the real device and not the emulator. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for helping. It worked twice, but I deleted the text file to try it again and it hasn't worked since. It doesn't make sense to me that it's not repeatable, any thoughts?

Comment: You can't see your app folder unless you have root access. If you see some app folders inside your internal storage, that's some folders for another purpose. If you root your phone/tablet, you'll get access of mnt/data/data folder so you will see all installed apps in their package name folders (com.something.someapp).
Try to make some test folder for you, and put new file into it, for example new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/test/"+"sensordata.txt");

Comment: I found out that if I just power off/on my phone, then I can now see the text file. Very strange. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
you cant see your app folder unless you hav root permission,but u will be able to see the file.


 File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+"sensordata.txt");

copy this code in your java file and try
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. It worked twice, but I deleted the text file to try it again and it hasn't worked since. It doesn't make sense to me that it's not repeatable, any thoughts?

Comment: of course it will work ,it will recreate file every time,may be u change some other codes